# Возможно ли отправить запрос, когда телефон в спящем режиме

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Возможно ли отправить запрос, когда телефон в спящем режиме? Приходит push уведомление, после этого, надо отправить запрос на сервер, но когда телефон в спящем режиме, запрос не отправляется.

Возможно это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что нужно выставить правильный [background mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Когда устройство в спящем режиме, приложения заморожены и не могут выполнять никаких операций, но есть несколько исключений:

1. Проигрывание аудио
2. Получение обновленных данных геолокации (от модуля GPS)
3. Предоставление сервиса VoIP (телефония)
4. Обработка загрузок из Newsstand (магазин журналов)
5. Взаимодействие с внешними устройствами (подключенными через порт наушников или Lightning)
6. Работа с Bluetooth (как хост или как сервер)
7. Выполнение загрузки данных в фоне
8. Обработка Push-нотификаций

Собственно, нужно показать системе, что приложение хочет работать в режиме №8. Для этого надо выставить значение `remote-notification` в параметре `UIBackgroundModes` в файле `Info.plist` проекта.

Дальше необходимо реализовать метод

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler {
    ...
}
```

в `AppDelegate`. Однако, если верить документации, всё это предназначено для загрузки контента при появлении пуша, чтобы пользователь после открытия нотификации в приложении не ждал загрузки данных, а сразу видел информацию. Для этого в сообщении должен быть выставлен флаг `content-available`, иначе чудо не произойдёт.

Comment: `remote-notification` указан, контент уведомления обрабатывается, но вот интернет соединения нет.

Comment: В документации настаивают на использовании `NSURLSession`, может через него попробовать? Вообще, есть какая-нибудь ошибка или не создаётся объект для отправки данных? Или вообще не вызывается обработчик?

Comment: Обработчик вызывается, объект создается, все идет хорошо, но после отправки нет ответа от сервера. Происходят только локальные действия, на iOS 8 и младше, даже локальные действия не поисходят, только обрабатывается push и все.

Comment: А есть возможность посмотреть на сервере что туда приходит? Или сниффером попробовать перехватить запрос, но это не самый простой путь...

Comment: До сервера сообщение не доходит, хотя дивайс говорит, что отправил.

Comment: Вот хорошая (хоть и старая) статья про фоновый режим: https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/multitasking/ Там есть пара моментов, которые стоит проверить. В остальном, видимо, проблема уже связана с нежеланием системы отправлять запрос, т.к. выполнение запросов в фоновом режиме не гарантируется, там много условностей.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, почитаю статью!